# How to use Sybprocess.call with rstrip and sed command in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm getting error when `shell=False` with sub process call but it's working when `shell=True`.

```
String = "geeks"
CriticalCmd = "/bin/sed -i /^cu\\:/c\\ '%s' a" %String.rstrip('s')
subprocess.call((replaceHashCmd),shell=False)
```

Comment: Show the error message as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: Error is:
Traceback (most recent call last): File "test.py", line 21, in <module> subprocess.call(replaceHashCmd,shell=False) File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait() File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in init errread, errwrite) File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child raise child_exception OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: But when i change shell=True it works, but not working with shell=False

Answer (score 0):

It's propbably because you calling `subprocess.call` with a tuple of one string and not list of strings (as the arguments of the shell)

change:
`subprocess.call((replaceHashCmd),shell=False)`

to:
`subprocess.call(replaceHashCmd.split(' '),shell=False)`

`.split` allow me to cut the string into the argument that i pass to the command line, like doing this :`'ls -l'.split() # ['ls', '-l']` which is all the args you passing to the command line

consider reading this post: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3172470/7434857)

Comment: I passed as you mentioned but still getting same error.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 21, in <module>
    subprocess.call(replaceHashCmd,shell=False)
  File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1327, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: But when i change shell=True it works, but not working with shell=False

Comment: @james also check this answer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3172488/7434857)

Comment: Yes it works..but can you tell me why you added 'split'

Comment: @james updated my answer, consider upvote my answer and mark it as correct if it the correct answer for you :)

Comment: How to use ONTAPE command with subprocess.call with Shell = False

import subprocess
import shlex
Cmd1 = "/bin/gunzip -c abc.gz"
Cmd2 = "ontape -r -v -t STDIO"

pip = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(Cmd1),shell=False,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    RC = os.WEXITSTATUS(subprocess.call(shlex.split(Cmd2),shell=False,stdin=pip.stdout))

Getting Error with Shell = False, It works when Shell= True

Comment: @james its a question for another stackoverflow question, if you think my asnwer is the right one for this problem, mark it as currect and vote it up :)